# How to get the other posts on a current post page

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-post-type, sidebar

I have custom post type called services which have taxonomies named service-categories.

Lets say I have added a taxonomy called A which has posts x,y,z . The single CPT pages must have a sidebar which displays other posts from the category.

For Eg: If we are on the post X page the sidebar needs to display Contents of Y,Z .  If we are Post Y page, the sidebar needs ti display Contents of X and Z and so on.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of `wp_reset_query()` - so in your sidebar:

```
query_posts('your_query_here');

if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();

  // Your code

endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

The function resets the page's query. Check out the [wp_reset_query() Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) for more info.

Comment: $args=array('post_type' => 'services','posts_per_page' => 99,  'taxonomy' => 'service_categories','term' => 'data','post_status' => 'publish');
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ( have_posts() ) :while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a><br /><?php
 endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();

Comment: So replace "your_query_here" with 'post_type=services&posts_per_page=99&taxonomy=service_categories&term=data&post_status=publish'

Comment: Then there is an issue with your query, ensure you're using all the correct values by trying it on another testing page.

Comment: I'd suggest using the `tax_query` query parameter. Change your query arguments to look like this: `$args = array( 'post_type' => 'services','posts_per_page' => 99, 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'service_categories', 'field' => 'slug','terms' => array( 'data' ) ) ), 'post_status' => 'publish' );`

Comment: @Tom - I tried on another page as well. Still the same, displays all of the posts –